# Multithreading in java Static method

Tags: java, multithreading, static, static-methods

I am writing a static utility method. I know methods `isEmpty()` and `isNew()` are threadsafe. In the `getTotal(...)` method I am using `StringBuilder` as parameter along with String and int. `StringBuilder` is mutable. Is `getTotal()` threadsafe? If so explain why it is even though StringBuilder is mutable. I am not sure if `getCharge()` is thread safe because it's invoking the method `getTotal()`. Can someone tell if it is threadsafe or not?

```
public class NewStringUtils {

    public static boolean  isEmpty(String s){
        return (s == null || s.trim().length()==0);
    }

    public static boolean isNew(String code){
        return( "1009".equals(code) || "1008".equals(code) );
    }
    //StringBuilder is  mutable  -- is the below method threadsafe 
    public static int getTotal(StringBuilder sb,String oldCode ,int a, int b){
        //Is it Threadsafe or not .If so  just bcz every thread invoking this method will have its own copy and other threads can't see its value ?? 
        int k =0;
        if("1011".equals(oldCode) && "1021".equals(sb.toString()) {
            k = a+b;
        }
        return k;
    }
     // is the below method threadsafe 
    public static int getCharge(String code,String oldCode,int charge1,int charge2){
        int total =0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("1021");
        if(!NewStringUtils.isEmpty(code)){

            if(NewStringUtils.isNew(code)){
                //here invoking a static method which has StringBuilder(Mutable) as a parameter
                total  = NewStringUtils.getTotal(sb,oldCode,charge1,charge2);
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`getTotal` is not `thread-safe` because it is possible that  two or more than two `threads` are  passing same reference of `StringBuilder` to the `getTotal` method as arguement and modifying the `StringBuilder` before passing it ...
And your `getCharge` is completely Thread-safe because here each `thread` is making local copy of `StringBuilder` Object in there own `stack`. So not to worry about thread safety of `getCharge`.
Here is the short Demo which is demonstrating why `getTotal` is not ThreadSafe:

```
class  ThreadSafe
{
    public static int getTotal(StringBuilder sb,String oldCode ,int a, int b)
    {
        int k =0;
        try
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " have sb as " + sb);
            Thread.sleep(100);//Added intentionally to show why it is not thread safe.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        if("1011".equals(oldCode) && "1021".equals(sb.toString())) 
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is within if loop");//Thread1 should be within this if block but it's not.
            k = a+b;
        }
        return k;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Thread th1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                sBuilder.append("1021");
                getTotal(sBuilder,"1011",10,20);
            }
        },"Thread1");
        Thread th2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                sBuilder.append("22");
                getTotal(sBuilder,"1011",10,20);
            }
        },"Thread2");
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
    }
}
```

At my system , the output is:

```
Thread1 have sb as 1021
Thread2 have sb as 102122
```

Assuming that `Thread1` started before `Thread2` which indeed happened here(as seen in output), If `getTotal` would have been `thread-safe` then , the statement ***Thread1 is within if loop*** must have been printed in output. But it is not . **WHY?** Because after `Thread1`(with sb = "1021") went to sleep in `getTotal` method the thread is preempted by `Thread2`. `Thread2` appended `22` to the existing `StringBuilder` object `sBuilder`(i.e the new value now is `102122`). Again when sleep method is called for `Thread2`, it is preempted by `Thread1`. `Thread1` goes to `if` construct , but till now the content of `sBuilder` is changed to `102122`. So if condition becomes false for `Thread1`. And it does'nt print that line `Thread1 is within if loop` which we were expecting if we consider `getTotal` to be thread-safe. Hence it proves that `getTotal` is not Thread-safe.
How can we make `getTotal` ThreadSafe?

> 1. By passing `String` instead of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @KevinMangold: yeah I rephrased my sentence.

Comment: @sarath: About which method are you  asking?

Comment: so will  getTotal()  be threadsafe if I always create a new StringBuffer object  and pass that as argument

Comment: If you change getTotal() to accept 2 strings instead of a StringBuilder and String, it will be thread-safe. StringBuffer is also a thread-safe version of String Builder.

Comment: A helpful link that describes the correct way to write static classes:[link Correct way to write static classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992475/how-to-write-correct-static-methods-multithread-safe?rq=1)

Comment: @sarath: Did it clarified you about why `getTotal` is not Thread-safe?

Comment: StringBuffer is threadsafe but mutable whereas StringBuilder is not threadsafe

Answer (score 3):

getTotal() is thread-safe in terms of being re-entrant (i.e., it can be called by multiple threads simultaneously). In terms of doing its job correctly, however, getTotal() is **not** thread-safe **if** another thread modifies the "sb" argument. This conditional safety should be explicitly stated in the documentation for that method.

If getTotal() were private rather than public and only called by getCharge(), then it would be unconditionally thread-safe.

Comment: "In terms of doing its job correctly, however, getTotal() is not thread-safe if another thread modifies the "sb" argument." By this do you mean to say the sb argument being modified by an other  thread which invoked the same static getTotal() method by passing a different StringBuffer argument  and modifying it.In which case the results can be unpredictable which is hard to replicate.In such a scenario the results of one thread will be receieved wrongly by another thread

Comment: To prevent getTotal() from doing its job correctly, the second thread  only needs to modify the "sb" argument that the first thread is using: the second thread doesn't need to call getTotal(). This is because StringBuilder isn't thread-safe; consequently, simultaneous access by multiple threads results in undefined behavior: calling "sb.toString()" in getTotal() might see all, some, or none of the changes from the second thread -- there's no a priori way to tell.

Answer (score 1):

The below is what Kevin wants to suggest. This is threadsafe:

```
//StringBuilder is  mutable  -- is the below method threadsafe 
public static int getTotal(String sb,String oldCode ,int a, int b){
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(sb); //we build out a new StringBuilder each time
    int k =0;
    if("1011".equals(oldCode) && "1021".equals(sb1.toString()) {
        k = a+b;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `getTotal` is that another thread may change the `StringBuilder` parameter. But you already know that. `StringBuilder` is usually implemented as a class with two fields let's say `int count` and `char[] value`. The Java Memory Model does not guarantee that changes to these variables from one thread will be published in the same order to the other threads. That makes it even possible to have `count` bigger than `value.length` for some threads. In this case you may see an exception. That means it can create problems even if you don't care about the latest value of the `StringBuilder`. In another cases `count` may be observed as 0 (for example) even though it has a different value for the modifying thread. This will lead to unexpected results.